# datetimepicker binding issues

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml, datetimepicker, windows-8.1

I'm trying to use the new dateTimePicker for Windows 8.1:

```
<DatePicker HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="401,245,0,0" Grid.Row="1"
 VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="352" Date="{Binding personSingle.personDOB,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

When ever I change the date I don't get the value that I chose when I look at value for personDOB.
personDOB is of type DateTimeOffset

What do I need to do get the value that I choose?

**Update:**

```
    <DatePicker x:Name="dtPick" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="401,245,0,0" Grid.Row="1" 
VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="352" DataContext="{Binding personSingle}"
 Date="{Binding personSingle.personDOB.Date,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Comment: Have you set `DataContext`?

Comment: @Xyroid - yeah I have done that.

Comment: Check if datepicker's datacontext is null or not.

Comment: It has data in it.  In face it has the right date too.  But my binding still says 1/1/0001

Comment: What are the datatype of `personSingle`, `personDOB` & `Date`?

Comment: @Xyroid - personSingle is just an object that contains DateTimeOffset personDOB and DateTime DOB

Comment: Use `DataContext="{Binding personSingle}` only & then try again & also check if values is null or not.

Comment: @Xyroid - it appears to have data.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the answer from this link:

http://bretstateham.com/binding-to-the-new-xaml-datepicker-and-timepicker-controls-to-the-same-datetime-value/

You need to write a converter to get this to work appropriately:

```
public class DateTimeToDateTimeOffsetConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        try
        {
            DateTime date = (DateTime)value;
            return new DateTimeOffset(date);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return DateTimeOffset.MinValue;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        try
        {
            DateTimeOffset dto = (DateTimeOffset)value;
            return dto.DateTime;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return DateTime.MinValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Never use try/catch in a logic flow! Replace it with an if/else. In this case `if(value is DateTime) { ... }  else { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

As it was explained to me, it is better to throw an exception when converting then to use a default.

```cs
public class DateTimeToDateTimeOffsetConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return new DateTimeOffset((DateTime)value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return ((DateTimeOffset)value).DateTime;
    }
}
```